# Cómo crear un identificador en firebase

Tags: firebase

Qué tal a todos, soy nuevo en firebase y estoy creando una base de datos, El problema es que todos los valores que estoy guardando  me los está guardando con un identificador muy largo, el predefinido de firebase.

Me gustaría mostrarlos en una tabla donde me muestre el ID con valor 1 y así subsecuente mente

Hay alguna propiedad en firebase que me permita hacer eso? Si no la hay, como puedo crear un identificador que me permita hacer esa enumeración

Estoy trabajando con firebase web

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenido. 
Siguiendo la documentación que proporciona firebase que la puedes consultar [aqui](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data), podemos usar el método set(), por ejemplo:

```
db.collection("cities").doc("new-city-id").set(data);
```

donde "cities" es tu colección y "new-city-id" será el id que quieras que tenga el documento a crear y 'data' los datos que quieras guardar

PD: para que se muestren en orden en tu tabla deberás de empezar a guardar desde 01.
Saludos!!!